# How can I assign an initial value to a variable in PuLP?

Tags: pulp

I am trying to solve a production problem and right now I need to assign an initial value to the inventory, and that value is given.
This is my definition of the inventory variable:

```
H = pl.LpVariable.dicts("H[i,t]", [(i,t) for i in productos for t in periodos],cat='Integer')
```

where:

```
productos=["golilla","tornillo","tuerca"]
periodos= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

and `H["golilla",0]` need to be 2400, `H["tuerca",0]` need to be 140 and `H["tornillo",0]` need to be 320

Comment: To assign a value to a variable, you can define it as a constraint. So, add a constraint that equals your decision variable to its initial value.

Answer (score 2):

In Pyomo you can use the `.fix()` method to do that. In the following example based on a condition you can fix some variables to different values:

```
if pyo.value(instance.x[2]) == 0:
   instance.x[2].fix(1)
else:
   instance.x[2].fix(0)
```

In PuLP:

Assigning values to variables also permit fixing those variables to that value. In order to do that, you can use the `fixValue` method of the variable.(Please look at [this](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_mip_start.html) link)

If you have not yet solved the model, you can use the `setInitialValue` method to assign a value to the variable.

For our example, if we know some variable needs to be 1, we can do:

```
_variable = x[('O', 'P', 'Q', 'R')]
_variable.setInitialValue(1)
_variable.fixValue()
```